# jQuery extend nested object

Tags: jquery, extend

When I try to extend an object, passing in a full object, it seems to overwrite the desired target object. However, I can extend each subobject individually, and then pass those in and it works.

```
$(function() {
    window.test = {};
    $.extend(window.test, {
        init: function(opts1, opts2) {
            //method 1, completely overwrites            
            this.options = $.extend({}, this.settings, {opts1: opts1, opts2: opts2});

            //method 2, works
            this.a = $.extend({}, this.settings.opts1, opts1);
            this.b = $.extend({}, this.settings.opts2, opts2);
            this.options2 = $.extend({}, this.settings, {opts1: this.a, opts2: this.b});

            console.log(this.options, this.options2);
        },
        settings: {
            opts1: {
                a: 'hello',
                b: 'hi',
                e: 'this still here?'
            },
            opts2: {
                c: 'yo',
                d: 'wassup'
            }
        }
    });
    test.init({ a: 'hello2', b: 'hello3' });
});
```

My question is if there is a way to utilize the first method (a 1 line, simple method) to achieve the results of the second method (individual subobjects).

Also, here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoL4dwsb/)**.

Comment: @crush yup... mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a deep-copy extends by passing `true` as the first parameter to `$.extend`. I believe that is what you are asking here.

```
this.options = $.extend(true, this.settings, {opts1: opts1, opts2: opts2});
```

See the second definition in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).